# how to setvalues multiple get range value from other spread sheet to another spread sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

i want from the range shUserForm Get Rang B14:B100 what ever record in it will send all the the data to dataSheet connection from other spreadsheet. but i only get 1 row data only not the whole range value.

dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B14:B100").getValue()); //PO/NAME Column Create Product

var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("InputForm");

//TO Create the Instance of the User-Inteface Enviroment tp use Alert features

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

var response=ui.alert("Submit", "Do you want to Submit the Record?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

if(response==ui.Button.NO) {

return;//Exit the submit response

}

/////////////////////////////////// - Connection to another Spreadsheet
SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
var myDataBarong = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1zwH6fMLG3N5eknt9lXqVwj8BJHTX-i9jTmXn_gZotTw');
var dataSheet= myDataBarong.getSheetByName("DATA");

var blankRow2=dataSheet.getLastRow()+1;

//Code to Update the Item Product

dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B14:B100").getValue()); //PO/NAME Column Create Product
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C14:C100").getValue()); //SKU Column Create Product
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D14:D100").getValue()); //QTY Column Create Product
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E14:E100").getValue()); //Vendor Column Create Product
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F14:F100").getValue()); //Small Column Create Product
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G14:G100").getValue()); //Medium Column Create Product
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D10").getValue()); //Large Column Create Product
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 8).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-mm-YYYY h:mm am/pm'); //TIME AND DATE Column Create Product
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 9).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); //Get User

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.